# ACF | Delete ACF value into array with "delete_field()"

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to remove an ACF value into a relation field, thanks to delete_field() function (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/delete_field/).

For your information, an ACF relation field is finally an array.
(https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/)

I tried the following example :

```
   $post_id = 2;
   $field = "field_63121dbf467be";
   $favori = get_field($field);
   // $favori = array(1,2,3);
   delete_field($field, $favori[$post_id]);
   // $favori = array(1,3)
```

Not working... The value "2" is not removed from the array.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't see it saying anywhere in the docs, that this could be used to delete a _partial_ value? Plus, what sense is it supposed to make passing `$favori[$post_id]` as second parameter? You did not explicitly pass any post ID when you _read_ the field value - so most likely your `delete` call is for a value stored under a completely different post id to begin with now. I think you should remove the element from your array, and then use `update_field` to write it back.

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for your response. Effectively may be I should use "unset($favori[VALUELINE]);" and update_field() ?